# how catch a segfault without core dump

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i am doing a program that must know if his child had segfault while executing.

for the segfault with core dump and without. for the first one i did it without probleme, but i cant find what could it be that make me un able to catch this signal. acording to man page i should receive 10,7,10, but im not sure of what it meant and i only can try one of them, but both 10 and 7 had done nothing

```
if (WTERMSIG(status) == 10)
    my_putstr("Segmentation fault \n");
else if (WTERMSIG(status) == 11)
    my_putstr("Segmentation fault (core dumped)\n");
```

Comment: Did you experiment with this code? What results did you get?

Comment: i already try it and it catch the segfault with core dump but not without

Comment: You should probably debug and see what status was returned in both cases, or if the status code even changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit unclear but you can use `WIFSIGNALED()` to check whether child process received any signal or not, if `WIFSIGNALED(status)` is true means child gets terminated abnormally by any signal.

```
if(fork() == 0 ) {
    /*... */
    /* send the exit status of child by calling exit()*/
}
else {
        int status;
        wait(&status);/* here parent collect exit status , now  parent wants to know--> normal termination or abnormal */

        if(WIFEXITED(status)) { /* true if terminates normally */
                printf("normally terminates\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
        if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) { /* if child terminated bcz of any other signal */             
                printf("terminated by signal\n",WTERMSIG(status));// bcz of what signal 
        }
}
```

To observe whether child received `SIGSEGV` without core dump, in above code once child receive `SIGSEGV` you can set signal handler by calling `sigaction()` & do some stuff.

Comment: i may had miss said it, my english is far from perfect. i want to know when a child segfault, and catch the segfault without core dump

Comment: Or you can use `pause()` in parent & set the handler for signal number `11`  as `pause()` blocks execution of parent until it not receive signal, but for that signal you need to change the by default action.

Answer (score 1):

> `if (WTERMSIG(status) == 10)
>        my_putstr("Segmentation fault \n");
>   else if (WTERMSIG(status) == 11)
>        my_putstr("Segmentation fault (core dumped)\n");`

Signal `10` is usually `SIGBUS` and signal `11` is usually `SIGSEGV`. They mean different things. Printing "segmentation fault" for *both* is confusing and wrong.

In addition, whether `core` was dumped or not is *orthogonal* to which of the above signals was received: if your `ulimit -c` is not 0, and the `core` destination is writable, then *both* signals will generate a `core`. Besides, *other* signals (e.g. `SIGILL`) will also generate a `core` by default.

Here is what you probably want:

```
if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
  printf("Terminated by signal %d%s\n", WTERMSIG(status),
         WCOREDUMP(status) ? " (core dumped)" : "");
}
```